# flutter - Migrar para Android embedding v2 - plugin audioplayers erro

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, kotlin, plugin

Estou com um probleminha um pouco chato (acredito eu). Hoje, mais cedo, estava trabalhando no meu app e estava tudo ok, mas agora de noite fui rodar e tive essa mensagem de erro:
[image: erro 1]

Atualizando para o Android embedding v2 (que sinceramente não entendi nada do que significa, só fui pesquisando e achando uns vídeos tutoriais) e rodando novamente o projeto, tive mais um erro:
[image: erro 2]

Dentro da pasta do audiplayers mencionada na imagem, tem o seguinte código:

```
    group 'xyz.luan.audioplayers'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Entendi que é um erro referente ao plugin audioplayers, mas não queria mudar o plugin, pois teria muito trabalho pra alterar todo o projeto. Alguém sabe como resolver?
Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: na verdade não e um bicho sete cabeça [documentacao](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration ) basta seguir a documentação caso não consiga estou aqui para ajudar

Comment: isso está relacionado ao Android X? achei que não tivesse nada a ver, pois sempre consegui rodar o programa mesmo sem estar com o Android X.

Acredito que o problema citado seja outro, seja referente a Android embedding v2.

Hoje a noite irei testar e retorno.